# ubuntu/apt-get update said "Failed to Fetch http:// .... 404 not found"

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, apt, ubuntu-9.10, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to run `apt-get update` on ubuntu 9.10

I've configured my proxy server and I can access the internet without any problem:

```
/etc/apt# wget "http://www.google.com"
Resolving (...)
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 292 [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'
100%[=================================================================================================================================>] 292         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2010-04-02 17:20:33 (29.8 MB/s) - `index.html' saved [292/292]
```

But when I tried to use **apt-get** I got the following message:

```
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic Release.gpg
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic Release.gpg       
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic Release   
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic/restricted Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic/restricted Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic Release
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates Release
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security Release
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/main Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/restricted Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/multiverse Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/restricted Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/main Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/universe Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/universe Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/main Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/restricted Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/multiverse Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/restricted Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/main Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/universe Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/universe Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/main Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/restricted Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/multiverse Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/restricted Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/main Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/universe Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/universe Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/main Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/restricted Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/multiverse Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/restricted Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/main Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/universe Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/universe Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/main Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/restricted Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/multiverse Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/restricted Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/main Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/universe Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/universe Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/main Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/restricted Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/multiverse Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/restricted Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/main Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/universe Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/universe Packages
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/main Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/restricted Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/multiverse Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic/universe Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/main Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/restricted Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/multiverse Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-updates/universe Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/main Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/restricted Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/multiverse Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr karmic-security/universe Packages
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic-updates/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic-updates/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic-updates/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic-security/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic-security/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic-security/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic-security/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/dists/karmic-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
```

**apt.conf**

However I can 'see' those files with firefox.

```
more /etc/apt/apt.conf
Acquire::http::proxy "http://www.myproxyname.fr:3128";
```

I also tried with port '80', or with a blank /etc/apt/apt.conf

**source.list**

```
grep -v "#" /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted multiverse
deb http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted multiverse
deb http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe
deb http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/ karmic-security main restricted multiverse
deb http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/ karmic-security universe
```

does anyone knows how to fix this ?

Thanks

Pierre

Answer (score 2):

For others whose problem isn't due to a broken proxy: you can always remove the host from your sources list. Normally, this would be as simple as removing the line from `/etc/apt/sources.list`. If that doesn't work, check if you have a `/etc/apt/sources.d/` directory and remove it from the appropriate file there.

Comment: This worked - for some reason I was using a Ubuntu Mirror that was broken, so moving to another mirror fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok **sorry**, the sysadmin came and corrected the URl for the proxy that was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How are you sure that wget is using the proxy? Is it the only way out?How are you sure that wget is using the proxy? Is it the only way out? Or what is your .wgetrc config file?

Off the top of my head it looks like proxy needs to be Proxy based on this [**info**](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/177).

Comment: I've configured the proxy with System > preferences > "Network Proxy" > (filled http proxy) and I clicked "Appply System wide"

~/.wgetrc does not exists

Comment: Try: Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxy.blah.fr:3128";